# Einer Sprache mächtig sein vs eine Sprache beherrschen

Tags: difference

> Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den zwei Ausdrücken  und sind sie austauschbar? Danke!

Comment: Welche Beispiele gibt es für den Kontext? Zeigen diese Beispiele eher Austauschbarkeit oder Unterschiede - so vom eigenen Verständnis her?

Answer (score 2):

Beide Ausrücke sind in ihrer Bedeutung sehr ähnlich aber nicht zu 100% deckungsgleich.

Die Nuancen sind allerdings gering, und es kann durchaus sein, dass der Unterschied nur in meinem persönlichen Sprachverständnis existiert.

Einer "Sprache mächtig sein" ist in meinen Augen der schwächere Ausdruck und bedeutet: Ich kenne die Sprache und bin auch einigermassen sicher in Verstehen und Sprechen, aber ich verstehe nicht unbedingt alles.

Wohingegen eine Sprache zu "beherrschen" -wie gesagt in meinen Augen- bedeutet: Ich verstehe einen sehr großen Anteil der Sprache, bin sehr sicher in Wort und Schrift und kenne auch die kleineren Nuancen.

Um Deine Frage quasi "rekursiv" zu beantworten:

Wer der deutschen Sprache mächtig ist stellt Deine Frage.
Wer sie aber beherrscht, der kann sie auch beantworten.

Comment: Datenpunkt in Sachen persönliches Sprachverständnis: Meines widerspricht dir. Es sieht beide Varianten als inhaltlich identisch an, findet aber, dass die »mächtig«-Variante etwas altbacken und gestelzt klingt.

Comment: Deshalb die Betonung auf "persönlich"... das mit dem "altbacken" und "gestelzt" kann ich aber zu 100% unterschreiben ;)